# Is it possible to access a specific key (not value) from a dictionary (JS)?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I know how to access all of the keys, all of the values, key-value pairs from a map, and accessing values individually, but is there a map method that will warrant access of a specific key? For instance:

```
const map = new Map () 
map.set ("Javascript",3) 
map.set ("Python",4)
```

How will I be able to access the string, "Javascript" alone?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. :) How would you access the "specific key"? What might the signature of this "map method" look like? How would you use it?

Comment: I would want to redeclare it in a piece of string. For example: I am learning + "javascript"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn the map into an array by using the spread operator and then use the array method `find` to find the correct item. In your `find` you can pass both the key and the value at the current iteration by wrapping them in brackets (`[k, v]`). The returned value will be an array with the key at the first index and the value as the second, so at the end of your `find` tack on a `[0]`.

Below is a quick function that accepts a `Map` and a `value` as arguments.

```js
const map = new Map () 
map.set ("Javascript",3) 
map.set ("Python",4) 

const getKey = (val, myMap) =>{
 return [...myMap].find(([key, value]) => val === value)[0]
}

let key = getKey(3, map)

console.log(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Map is an ordered list of key-value pairs. So you can create a new iterator of the keys and then get the first element.

See here for more information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot! Simply creating a new variable holding all the keys and implementing a newvariablename.next().value method works.

Comment: I'm glad it helped ^_^

Answer (score 0):

map1.keys will give you a iterator and with next method you can access the next key
for eg

`const map1 = new Map();`

`map1.set('0', 'foo'); map1.set(1, 'bar');`

`const iterator1 = map1.keys();`

`let key=iterator1.next().value`

`while(key!=undefined){ console.log(key) key=iterator1.next().value }`